# Photo is not showing properly

Tags: images

I have created a banner after the header which is working fine on desktop view but now on phone view. Here is the example:
[image]

here is the example of phone view:
[image]

as you can see in the images, photo is not showing properly in the phone.

I am using PopularFX theme and created this section through "Kadence Blocks – Gutenberg Blocks" row layout.
Anybody know how to fix it?

Page URL for search purpose: https://lillestromflytt.no/lager-lillestrom/

Comment: you mentioned it isn't showing right on mobile but never stated what you wanted it to look like. Keep in mind that a row is supposed ot linearise into a column when the screen is small so if the problem is that the image is underneath then that's exactly how a row is supposed to work. If you need further help with Kadence blocks though you'll need to ask their support or other users in a dedicated community as 3rd party product support is offtopic here and not in this stacks scope

Comment: a quick look reveals that the image is only 10/15px tall, and this is because there's nothing inside the block to give it height. On desktop it expands to fill the vertical height of the left block as they're side by side. Try a spacer block or a cover block with a minimum height set ( nothing I'm seeing requires kadence blocks, and can be done with standard cover group/row and columns blocks

Comment: spacer block sounds good, let me give it a try

Comment: thanks Tom, It worked